# Query category and show title of the post only in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, post, categories

Query category posts and show title of the post only, i want the code. Please.
Let us say, the category ID is 50.. So I'll be seeing title of the posts under the category 50.(Wordpress) Thanks :D

Comment: What did you try actually ?...

Comment: <?php query_post("cat=51&showposts=5"); ?>
<?php the_title('<h3>', '</h3>'); ?>

Comment: i tried that code but it doesnt show any.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your code in the comments your problem is that you have left out the WordPress Loop - take a look at the Code in this link;

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts

The example given is very similar to your task.

Answer (score 1):

In WordPress query, you need to call title/content functions etc in loop such as:

```
<?php
query_posts( 'cat=51&showposts=5' );
// the Loop
while (have_posts()) : the_post();
    the_title('<h3>', '</h3>');
endwhile;
?>
```